# ng-init ,copy value from other controller

Tags: angularjs, ng-init

I would like to copy value from one controller to second controller.

If code looks like that everything works fine. Value is chosen and sent to other controller as a value.

```
  <select ng-model="feeCatCtrl.addNewSubCategoryData.MainCategory = feeCategory.newFee.MainCategory" class="form-control" name="MainCategory">
  </select>
```

But if code looks like that, is not.

```
<select ng-init="feeCatCtrl.addNewSubCategoryData.MainCategory = feeCategory.newFee.MainCategory" ng-model="feeCatCtrl.addNewSubCategoryData.MainCategory" class="form-control" name="MainCategory">                        
</select>
```

Can somebody explain to me why?

Comment: as specified in official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) you **should not** use `ng-init` except some rare situations. do your logic in controllers instead.

Comment: take a look at angular directives... you are probably trying to implement a behaviour that is natural to them (communication between controllers)